# Linux alternative to Adobe Digital editions

Tags: gratis, linux, ebooks

I want to download a free eBook from the eLibrary of my university. It only opens in [Adobe Digital editions](http://www.adobe.com/products/digital-editions.html) which is only available to Mac and Windows. It's a `.acsm` file.

Is there any native Linux client that works on Ubuntu 14.04? (I have Xubuntu 14.04 64 bit.)

I want a gratis one, not necessarily open source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a program called [Knock](https://github.com/esn/knock) to convert ACSM files to DRM-free EPUB files at the command line:

```
[user@computer:~]$ knock ./example.acsm
downloading the file from Adobe...
removing DRM from the file...
DRM-free EPUB file generated at ./example.epub
```

The program is gratis and libre. This isn't a client/reader per se, it just let's you convert the ACSM file to a DRM-free EPUB file, which you can then read with any gratis EPUB reader. It also works for ACSM files that point to PDFs.

Comment: This is an interesting project, thanks for letting me know, I accepted the answer because apparently, it's a solution to the problem. However, I have not tested it because  I'm no longer a student so I don't have access to the ebooks. Hopefully, someone could give it a try and let us know. Thank you for your efforts in creating the project

Comment: Does this also work for PDFs?

Comment: @Jonathan yes it does work for PDFs

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know there is no easy solution for this. There is no ADE for Linux, and since the .acsm file isn't the book itself but just a purchase ticket that allows you to download the book on Adobe's servers, it makes it harder to create a program that would fool Adobe's servers to retrieve the book content with the .acsm. It seems like the best you can do is [using Wine](http://blog.greenpirate.org/a-wine-remedy-for-acsm-epub-drm-adobe-ades/) (and complain to the eLibrary of your university that you don't spend $$$ in tuition fees to get books full of DRMs)

Another solution: [Converting a ADE document (Adobe Digital Editions, acsm) to PDF](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/27799/903).

Comment: hopefully they hear what I say :)

Comment: Winetricks actually comes with an installer for ADE, making the process a snap. (I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and I used the Winetricks GUI.)

Comment: @Lynob Another solution would be [converting a ADE document (Adobe Digital Editions, acsm) to PDF](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/27799/903).

Comment: it's your question and still unsolved right? so still no answer

Comment: @Lynob that's another approach, and if you are willing to pay I pointed to a tool that might work.

Comment: ahhh got it! and thanks for remembering my question from a year ago! back then we would have said happy new year 2015 :)

Answer (score 2):

I will try to list all the solutions I've found.

1. Tested solution: It's working, and very easy.

   First install *Wine* on your Linux OS. Then download [Adobe Digital editions](https://www.adobe.com/solutions/ebook/digital-editions/download.html).

   Then install the file you downloaded from Adobe (It was ADE_4.5_Installer.exe, for me), in the Wine virtual Window. If you don't know how to use wine, see this doc: [How to install and use Wine on Linux](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-install-and-use-wine-run-windows-applications-linux)
2. Install a Virtual Windows guest OS on Linux. [How to Set Up a Windows Virtual Machine in Linux](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/set-windows-virtual-machine-linux/).
3. If you failed to install virtual machine or open with Wine, and if you really need this program, install a Windows/Linux dual boot on your computer. [How to dual boot Windows/Linux on the same computer](https://www.howtogeek.com/214571/how-to-dual-boot-linux-on-your-pc/%20%22How%20to%20dual%20boot%20Windows/Linux%20on%20the%20same%20computer)
4. Use a virtual Android phone (or a real one) and install the Adobe Digital editions for Android. [Virtual smartphone software, Memu](http://www.memuplay.com)

You can also try to emulate MacOS, or iOS.