# Converting a ADE document (Adobe Digital Editions, acsm) to PDF

Tags: gratis, pdf, document-converter, drm

I have downloaded a book from Google Play. The book is a `.acsm`, which actually isn't the book itself but just a purchase ticket that allows me to download the book on Adobe's servers. I installed Adobe Digital Editions on my computer and downloaded the book. Which programs allow me export the book into a DRM-free PDF?

Any OS or license is fine, but it should be gratis (unlike [ebook-converter.com's ePub to PDF Converter](http://www.ebook-converter.com/19-convert-digital-editions.htm)).

---

This is how I exported the book from [Google Play's My Books](https://play.google.com/books):

[image: Google Play;s My Books Export Menu]

In ADE, the print function is grayed out, so I cannot get away with virtual printers it seems:

[image: Adobe Digital Editions File Menu]

Comment: I've heard there were some Calibre recipes for that (to free eBooks from DRM) – but as I never needed that, I've not dug deeper. While waiting for answers, that might be something you want to look into. [Search for "calibre remove drm"](https://www.google.com/search?q=calibre+remove+drm) to find the articles. Calibre is free/gratis, so it should match your needs.

Comment: Franck: How did you download the ebook in ADE? In ADE, what menu items did you select to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use **[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)** for this, which was already [recommended multiple times for book conversion](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=calibre+is%3Aanswer+convert). An Article named [DeDRM plugin for calibre](https://apprenticealf.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/calibre-plugins-the-simplest-option-for-removing-most-ebook-drm/) describes a plugin to achieve exactly that:

> The DeDRM plugin can remove DRM from Kindle eBooks […], Barnes & Noble ePub ebooks […], **any ebooks using Adobe Digital Editions DRM**, and the older Mobipocket and eReader ebooks.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

The article describes in detail how to install, customize and use the DeDRM plugin, and was obviously written by the plugin's author. The plugin itself [can be found at Github](https://github.com/apprenticeharper/DeDRM_tools).

While I'm using *Calibre* for years (and am quite happy with it), I have not tried that addon myself. But seeing it having been starred at Github almost 1.000 times, forked almost 100 times, and watched more than 100 times, seems pretty convincing :)

---

Step-by-step instructions for Microsoft Windows 7.

1. Install DeDRM pluging:

[image: Calibre Preferences Menu]

[image: Calibre Preferences Plugins]

[image: Calibre Add plugin window]

2. Import ADE books into Calibre (The DeDRM calibre plugin removes DRM from ebooks as they are imported into calibre):

[image: Select books window]
[image]

[image: Adding books]

3. Save the DRM-free PDF somewhere else on the disk:

[image]

Comment: Glad to read, @FranckDernoncourt – and thanks for adding the details!

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt and Izzy   Thanks. Does this method work on Ubuntu, given that  Calibre works on Ubuntu? Is it free, though [if you are willing to pay I pointed to a tool that might work.](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6959/linux-alternative-to-adobe-digital-editions?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment39487_6961)

Comment: @Tim afraid neither Franck (who according to the screenshots uses it on Windows) nor myself (I run Linux Mint, but never had any ADE documents nor do I want to) have tried it on Ubuntu. If you do, be welcome to let us know!

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt and Izzy I downloaded an ebook from a library. It has `.acsm` extension (Adobe Content Server Message), and only 2kB. It is not actually a ebook. Now I can access the book only in browser. Is it possible to  download the book, so that I can try the method here?

Comment: Downloaded an eBook in Adobe Digital Editions (4.5) to my Windows laptop (8.1). Used this to get the pdf. It worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: @Sarah How did you download the ebook in ADE? In ADE, what menu items did you select to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I created a program called [Knock](https://github.com/BentonEdmondson/knock) to convert ACSM files to DRM-free PDF files at the command line on Linux:

```
[user@computer:~]$ knock ./example.acsm
downloading the file from Adobe...
removing DRM from the file...
DRM-free PDF file generated at ./example.pdf
```

The program is gratis and libre. It doesn't use Adobe Digital Editions and it doesn't use Wine. It is completely free and open-source software for native Linux.

Comment: Link now goes to 404.